# how to debug Gin Web Framework

Tags: go, go-gin

I am using Go [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) for REST API. In ruby on rails application i can debug using debugger or pry. How can i do same in gin framework?

Edited:
consider the following request.

```
curl -X GET  localhost:5005/test_controller/test_action --data '{ "sw_lat" : 83.4444, "sw_lon" : -171.232323, "ne_lat" : 82.2323232, "ne_lon" : -161.3434343}'  -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

### Ruby on Rails:

To inspect the above request in server i can put `debugger` like the following.

```
def test_action
  debugger
end
```

after starting server using `rails s` and hit the request, the server will pause in debugger line. And it will allow me to inspect something.

### Go:

`dlv debug` does not start the server. So I can not hit and inspect the above request. Help me to set breakpoint and to debug while the server is running.

Comment: Hi @Gurunath, did you find the solution for this? I'm stuck here also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve) debugger either through the command line or with the [editor integrations](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/blob/master/Documentation/EditorIntegration.md).

Gin also has logger and recovery middleware which should be enough to diagnose basic routing issues etc.

Comment: Thanks Teoman Soygul. I tried this. But I don't know how to use delve when the server is running. I need to inspect stack while the server process the request. can you give some document links?

Comment: @Gurunath start the server with delve: `dlv debug gopath/to/package`. Alternatively, delve has really good Visual Studio Code integration via lukehoban's Go plugin.